# AngularJS seems to be working but ng-repeat is not

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm stumped and can't find the bug.

Angular is working, because it's reading my {{expressions}}, however, it's not replacing them with the content I'm expecting. It's simply removing them and blanks sit in their place.
I'm sure this issue is also tied in with, for some reason, my ng-repeat directive isn't working. (It's not repeating.)

Can someone help me out? I'm trying to draw a table. In this example, when it's done, it should have the respective "idea" posted multiple times across the same row, and each row should have a different "idea", as listed in the $scope.

It's creating one single row filled with blanks (rather than {{idea}} ).

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="AppName">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/table.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="TableController">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellspacing="0">
                    <tr class="title_bar">
                        <td>Title</td>
                        <td>Rating</td>
                        <td>Votes</td>
                        <td>Comments</td>
                        <td>Post Date</td>
                        <td>Status</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <div ng-repeat="idea in ideas">
        <tr style="color: white">
            <td>{{idea}}</td>
            <td>{{idea}}%</td>
            <td>{{idea}}</td>
            <td>{{idea}}</td>
            <td>{{idea}}</td>
            <td>{{idea}}</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="scripts/controllers/TableController.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**TableController.js**

```
var app = angular.module('AppName', []); 

app.controller('TableController', ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.ideas = [
        'wow',
        'cool',
        'so nice',
        'amazing',
        'please work'
    ];
}]);
```

I'm probably missing something obvious but I appreciate any help you could give me.

**Edit:** Whoops, guess I need to brush up on my HTML basics.

Comment: A div inside a table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your HTML layout looks pretty strange. You shouldn't put `<div>` between `<tr>`

Try something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr class="title_bar">
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Rating</td>
        <td>Votes</td>
        <td>Comments</td>
        <td>Post Date</td>
        <td>Status</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="idea in ideas">
        <td>{{idea}}</td>
        <td>{{idea}}%</td>
        <td>{{idea}}</td>
        <td>{{idea}}</td>
        <td>{{idea}}</td>
        <td>{{idea}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PFU2Y/)

Answer (score 1):

What you have is invalid HTML, so it's not rendering how you expect it to. You can't put a `<div>` inside a `<table>` and have it contain  elements; you can include a `<div>` inside a `<td>` element but that doesn't really help you.

If you want to use ng-repeat in a table use it in `<tr>` or `<tbody>`

```
        <tr ng-repeat="idea in ideas">
            <td>{{idea}}</td>
            ........
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `ng-repeat` directive to the `td` itself.

```
<tr>
  <td ng-repeat="idea in ideas">{{idea}}</td>
</tr>
```

That should iterate through your `$scope.ideas` array.